# How do I get a grid type date columnMenu: true/{...} datetimepicker show the timepicker?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I can get the following to work and show a datepicker and timepicker:

1) grid with a column type date, columnMenu: not set to true,

I can't get the following to work. It only show the datepicker and not the timepicker:

2) grid with a column type date, columnMenu: set true/{...}

Below are some examples:

This works and shows both the date and time pickers:

[jsfiddle grid date filter no columnMenu both date and time pickers show up](http://jsfiddle.net/elbarto99/2jpvug1r/)

This doesn't work and only show the date picker but now time picker:

[jsfiddle grid date columnMenu: true/{...} filter only date picker shows up](http://jsfiddle.net/elbarto99/rsa7yqwj/)

How do I get the time picker to show up if I use the columnMenu:?
I'm using the datetimepicker but only the datepicker shows up.

```
    // TODO: Make datetimepicker filter show the timepicker next the to datepicker when 
    //       columnMenu: is used
    columnMenu:
    {

        filterable:   { ui: "datetimepicker" }, // Partial - Date picker is shown, no time picker shown
        //filterable:   { ui: "datepicker" },     // Works   - Date picker is shown
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ui` is part of the `filterable` defined for each `column` not defined in `columnMenu`. Your definition should be:

```
columnMenu: {
    filterable: true
},
height: 200,
columns: [
    { 
        field: "title", 
        title: "Title",
        width: "270px"
    },
    {
        field: "date5", 
        title: "D 5",
        width: "230px",
        format:"{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt}",
        filterable: {
            ui: "datetimepicker"
        }
    }
```

Your JSFiddle modified here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/rsa7yqwj/2/